# What are the key differences between laika, RTD and Safety Harness for testing Meteor applications?

Tags: testing, meteor, laika

Laika, RTD and Safety Harnesss are testing frameworks for Meteor.

- http://arunoda.github.io/laika/
- http://xolvio.github.io/rtd/
- http://safety-harness.meteor.com

What are the key differences between these projects? What are the pros and cons of each?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a high-level perspective, RTD is more fully featured and is primarily aimed at:

- acceptance testing
- unit testing
- coverage reporting

Laika is lighter-weight and is squarely focused on:

- integration testing

You could do acceptance testing with Laika and integration testing with RTD... but its much easier to use a tool specifically designed for the job.

Here's a comparison chart outlining the differences:

http://safety-harness.meteor.com/comparison

At the time of writing there are still a few issues with the comparison (RTD does acceptance testing rather than integration) but its a nice overview.

Comment: Great answer, and also liked your detailed [post on meteor-talk about the differences between RTD and Laika](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/J_UFdK7530k/doVMqScEPWAJ).

Comment: Thanks Dan!  Glad you found it useful!